# How to manually set the attribute 'name' when Serializing

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

it seems to me that the answer is quite simple, but I could not manage to find an it, how do I change the name attribute when serialising using DRF? Check the circle in the image, I just got it from the DRF website in the Metadata section.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified on the documentation on [*metadata* [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/metadata/). You probably use the [**`SimpleMetadata`** class [GitHub]](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/335054a5d36b352a58286b303b608b6bf48152f8/rest_framework/metadata.py#L29). Here we see that the options are determined with:

> ```
>     def determine_metadata(self, request, view):
>         metadata = OrderedDict()
>         metadata['name'] = view.get_view_name()
>         metadata['description'] = view.get_view_description()
>         metadata['renders'] = [renderer.media_type for renderer in view.renderer_classes]
>         metadata['parses'] = [parser.media_type for parser in view.parser_classes]
>         if hasattr(view, 'get_serializer'):
>             actions = self.determine_actions(request, view)
>             if actions:
>                 metadata['actions'] = actions
>         return metadata
> ```

The [`get_view_name` of a `APIView` [GitHub]](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/views.py#L231-L237) is implemented as:

> ```
>     def get_view_name(self):
>         """
>         Return the view name, as used in OPTIONS responses and in the
>         browsable API.
>         """
>         func = self.settings.VIEW_NAME_FUNCTION
>         return func(self)
> ```

The `settings` will thus by default determine the name of the function that calculates the view. This is specified by the [**`VIEW_NAME_FUNCTION`** setting [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#view_name_function) that defaults to `'rest_framework.views.get_view_name'`.

If we inspect the [source code of this `get_view_name` function [GitHub]](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/views.py#L22-L44), we see:

> ```
> def get_view_name(view):
>     """
>     Given a view instance, return a textual name to represent the view.
>     This name is used in the browsable API, and in OPTIONS responses.
>     This function is the default for the `VIEW_NAME_FUNCTION` setting.
>     """
>     # Name may be set by some Views, such as a ViewSet.
>     name = getattr(view, 'name', None)
>     if name is not None:
>         return name
>
>     name = view.__class__.__name__
>     name = formatting.remove_trailing_string(name, 'View')
>     name = formatting.remove_trailing_string(name, 'ViewSet')
>     name = formatting.camelcase_to_spaces(name)
>
>     # Suffix may be set by some Views, such as a ViewSet.
>     suffix = getattr(view, 'suffix', None)
>     if suffix:
>         name += ' ' + suffix
>
>     return name
> ```

If your view thus contains a `.name` attribute, it will use that as the name. You thus can implement your `APIView` as:

```
class SomeAPIView(APIView):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.name = 'Another name than To Do List'
```

If there is no `name` attribute, it will thus take the name of the view, try to get rid fo the `View` or `ViewSet` suffix, convert the camelcase to spaces, and optionally add a suffix (like `'List'` for an `ListAPIView`).